# In R, how to use reticulate to import mplsoccer

Tags: python, r, anaconda, reticulate

I'm trying to import a python package (`mplsoccer`) via `reticulate` package but I can't:
`reticulate::py_install('mplsoccer')`

This is the message I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mplsoccer

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

As I am a beginner in python I am lost. Any help uys?

This is the package page: https://github.com/andrewRowlinson/mplsoccer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available through Conda, but is on PyPI. Try instead:

```
reticulate::py_install('mplsoccer', pip=TRUE)
```

See [documentation on `py_install` command](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_install.html).